# How to monitor SQLite performance?

Tags: sqlite, monitoring

I can't seem to find an application to monitor SQLite DB performance. Currently I have a test server that uses SQLite. I'm primarily concerned with obtaining a benchmark of storage requirements and performance for scaling this server to production.

I know for MySQL there is the standard Nagios for monitoring (changing to mySQL is not an option at this point). Is there anything analogous for SQLite?

Comment: Generally sqlite is not recommended for a production database. It would make more sense to use something like Postgresql if mySQL is not an option. By the way, what language are you using which restricts you to not changing the database type?

Comment: It's not a technical restriction, but an time-constraint/operational restriction.

Comment: OK. Just a suggestion. I actually know nothing about database monitoring, so I can't help you there, sorry!

Comment: @thesecretmaster There are quite a few applications where SQLite would be the [appropriate DB to use](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html).

Comment: @CL. Well! You learn something new every day! Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite has functions like [sqlite3_status()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/status.html) and [sqlite3_db_status()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/db_status.html), but those do not really give you the information you want, and might not even be available in all languages.

Anyway, SQLite is an embedded library, so you'd have to monitor your actual application. Tools like Nagios allow to monitor a server's CPU load and disk usage, but you can also use any other tool of your OS.